# Keeping Table Header Fixed in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor-2

I have a Table for which I need to keep the header fixed. The code for the table is as below:

```
@Html.Grid(Model).Columns(column =>
{
     column.For(m => m.Id).Attributes(@class => "HideColumn").HeaderAttributes(@class => "HideHeader");                                   
     column.For(m => m.HolidayName).Named("Holiday Name").Attributes(@style => "width:300px;");
     column.For(m => m.HolidayDetails).Named("Holiday Details ").Attributes(@style => "width:300px;");
     column.For(m => m.Status).Named("Status").Attributes(@style => "width:200px;"); 
}
```

How to do this? Thanks in advance.  :)

Comment: Did this solution work for you? I'm trying to do the same thing in my MVC app but the plugin does not work. I'm wondering if it's how I set it up in the bunding. I simply added the .js file and then made the call to .freezeHeader(). I did not include the downlowded CSS because I have my own to style the table.

Comment: @Ray  were you guys able to achieve this ? like Ray I tried but could get it to work on GridMVC

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Grid in MVC will be rendering as normal HTML table (at least in my understanding you are using MVC Grid Nugets like [Grid.MVC](http://gridmvc.codeplex.com/)) on the client side. So you can use any HTML Table Fixed header JQuery plugins to fix the header.

Some options what you have is -

[JQuery FreezeHeader](http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Simple-jQuery-Plugin-To-Freeze-Header-Row-In-Table-freezeheader/) in which you can simply have -

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#tableid").freezeHeader();
        })
```

And some more options are - [Fixed Header Table](http://fixedheadertable.com/), [Sticky Table Headers](https://github.com/jmosbech/StickyTableHeaders) etc.

Comment: I couldn't get it work on GridMVC and working samples pls

Answer (score 1):

you can use this code in script section:

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
                $('#yourTableId').floatThead({
                    top: $('.topbar').height(),
                    autoReflow: true,
                    zIndex: 1
                });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to add

```
<script src="/path/to/jquery.freezeheader.js"></script>
```

;-)