# Freezing html header with width 100%

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am freezing the headers of my table, so when you scroll down. The header stays.

Using freezeHeader by Laerte Mercier Junior recommended [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21599415/keeping-table-header-fixed-in-mvc)

That works fine.

However, if you **scroll down**, then **Adjust the window width** (aka table width), a **duplicate header appears**. (My table width is set to 100%, which it seems to dislike)

NOTE: I have made the header clear background, so you can see the duplicate one behind. So ignore the ability to see row data through the header.

The issue is that, if you scroll a bit, then make the Window SMALLER, you can then scroll right to see the full header (It does not scale).

Ive used a generic table with width 100%:

```
<table class="gridView" id="table1" style="width:100%">
```

Calling

```
$("#table1").freezeHeader({
   'height': '300px'
});
```

Issue can be seen in fiddler:
http://jsfiddle.net/pXC3C/

Scroll, then change window size to make it smaller - scroll bar right appears, + duplicate header

Comment: @Aravona Yes, which is not an issue in theory, as you can never see the one at the back.. until you change the window width, and it extrudes beyond the other wrongly as it does not scale smaller.

Comment: why not use css instead of the plugin..? http://jsfiddle.net/Lr4r6/1/ you would only need to change a line in the css incase your headers become more than 1 line.. but other than that it works :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing:

```
if (params && params.height !== undefined) {
            container.css("top", obj.offset().top + "px");
            container.css("position", "absolute");
        }
```

with:

```
if (params && params.height !== undefined) {
            container.css("top", obj.offset().top + "px");
            container.css("position", "absolute");
            container.width("calc(100% - 33px)");
        }
```

Comment: That works perfect.. but why -33px? Is this the width of the scroll bar or something

Comment: -33px was the width of the scroll bar yes. Otherwise the 100% would cover the bar when you scroll down, and flicked back when you scrolled back up to the top. -33px worked for me to prevent this.

Answer (score 1):

where I had met a similar question I think you will here it, I think this example will help you [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/8cg4f/594/)

**HTML**

```
<table class="tablesorter" cellspacing="1">
<thead>
<tr>
<th>first name</th>
<th>last name</th>
<th>age</th>
<th>total</th>
<th>discount</th>
<th>date</th>
</tr>
</thead>
.....
```